How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan^2(x^2)}{x^2 \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, dx $

Question

How to evaluate
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan^2(x^2)}{x^2 \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, dx
$$

My attempt

$$
I = \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan^2(x^2)}{x^2 \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, dx
$$
Taking into account the power series expansion of $\arctan^2(x)$, we have:
$$
\arctan^2(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} S_k x^{2k+2}
$$
where $S_k = \sum_{j=0}^{k} \frac{1}{2j + 1}$. Thus, we can write the integral as:
$$
I = \int_0^1 \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} S_k x^{4k+2}}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, dx
$$
It is easy to verify that:
$$
S_k = \int_0^1 \frac{1 - w^{2k+2}}{1 - w^2} \, dw = 2(k+1) \int_0^1 \left( \int_w^1 \frac{s^{2k+1}}{1 - w^2} \, ds \right) dw
$$
This can be simplified to:
$$
S_k = 2(k+1) \int_0^1 z^{2k+1} \int_0^z \frac{1}{1 - w^2} \, dw \, dz = (k+1) \int_0^1 z^{2k+1} \log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right) \, dz
$$
Therefore, the integral $I$ becomes:
$$
I = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k (zx^2)^{2k+1} \right) \log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right) \, dz \, \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}
$$
This can be simplified to:
$$
I = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{zx^2}{1 + z^2 x^4} \log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right) \, dz \, \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}
$$
Now I am completely stuck. Better solutions are welcome, or can someone help me with where I got stuck?

Why do you think that you can find a closed form ? For Wolfram no closed form seems to exist.

@Surb I don't know if there is a closed form of the integral or not because this is just exploration. The original integral only had $\arctan(x)$, but I modified it for exploration purposes.

Why downvote???

The following identity may help you:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{4n}{2n}\frac{x^{2n}}{4^{2n}}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x}}\text{arctanh}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}}\text{arctanh}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1-x}}\log\frac{x}{2(x-1)}+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1+x}}\log\frac{x}{2(1+x)}$$

Your integral is equal to \begin{align}\sqrt{2}\int_0^\infty\arctan^2\left(\frac{1}{1+2x^2}\right)dx\end{align}

By using contour integration we can show that  $2I=-4\pi\Im\left(\alpha\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\text{arccoth}(x^2)}{x^2\sqrt{\alpha^2 x^2-1}} \right)$ and $\alpha= e^{i \pi/4}$. This integral can be done in closed form (elementary antiderivative). I won't embark on this messy journey , but the final result should be
$$2 I=\frac{\pi \left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} \pi -\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \log \left(1088-768 \sqrt{2}\right)\right)}{2\ 2^{3/4}}\approx 1.152670485
$$

@tired  Welcome back.

Use the substitution
$x^2=\frac{1}{u^2+1}$
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2(x^2)}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int_0^\infty\arctan^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)dx$$
Use integration by parts with $u=\arctan^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right),\space dv=dx$
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{4x^2}{x^4+2x^2+2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)dx=-4\Im\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln(x^2+1-i)}{(x^2+1-i)(x^2+1+i)}dx$$
This can be finished using partial fractions and the following integral identity, which can be proved easily using a double integral or Leibniz's rule.
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(x^2+a)}{x^2+b}dx=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt b}\ln(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)$$
$$\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1-i)(x^2+1+i)}=\frac{\frac{1-i}{2}}{x^2+1+i}+\frac{\frac{1+i}{2}}{x^2+1-i}$$
$$I=-4\Im\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{1-i}{2}\frac{\ln(x^2+1-i)}{x^2+1+i}+\frac{1+i}{2}\frac{\ln(x^2+1-i)}{x^2+1-i}\right) dx$$$$=-2\Im\left((1-i)\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1+i}}\ln(\sqrt{1-i}+\sqrt{1+i})+(1+i)\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1-i}}\ln(\sqrt{1-i}+\sqrt{1-i})\right)$$
WolframAlpha simplifies this to
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2^{7/4}}\left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\ln\left(\frac{3+2\sqrt2}{8}\right)+\pi\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}{2}\right)$$

Thanks a lot! To be honest, I didn’t even expect the closed form.

Integrate in real space as follows\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2x^2}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\overset{x=\cos \theta} {dx}\\
= &\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\arctan^2\cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}d\theta
\overset{ibp}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{4\sin^2 \theta\ \arctan\cos^2\theta}{1+\cos^4\theta}d\theta\\
=& \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^1 \frac{4\sin^2 \theta\cos^2\theta}{(1+\cos^4\theta)(1+t^2 \cos^4\theta)}dt\ d\theta\\
=&\ \sqrt2\pi\int_0^1 \frac1{1-t^2}\left({\sqrt{\sqrt2+1}-\sqrt{\sqrt{1+t^2}+1}}\right)dt\\
=& \ \sqrt2\pi\ \bigg[\sqrt a\arctan\sqrt{a(\sqrt{1+t^2}+1)} \\
&\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>-\frac1{2\sqrt a}\ln \frac{(\sqrt a-\sqrt{\sqrt{1+t^2}-1} )(1+t)}{(\sqrt a+\sqrt{\sqrt{1+t^2}-1})(1-t)}\ \bigg]_0^1\\
=&\ \frac\pi{\sqrt{2a}}\bigg[\frac{\pi a}4-\ln(1+a^2) \bigg]
\end{align}
where $a=\sqrt2-1$.
